# PHP, Jquery get multi array, combine a row

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel

Concept:
Adding Floors and Room counts and Room Numbers in a Hotel and saving it in a db

Front end Design:

Please have a look at this image

[image]

Backend what i am getting now:

```
 "floor" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "3"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  "room_count" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "3"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "5"
  ]
  "room_number" => array:11 [▼
    0 => "101"
    1 => "102"
    2 => "103"
    3 => "201"
    4 => "202"
    5 => "203"
    6 => "101"
    7 => "102"
    8 => "103"
    9 => "104"
    10 => "105"
  ]
```

The Question is:

How can i loop through to get:
Floor 3 has the room numbers 101, 102, 103
Floor 2 has the room numbers 201, 202, 203
Floor 1 has the room numbers 101, 102, 103, 104, 105

Comment: you need to have the room_number array indexes according to the value of the floors in the first array , otherwise you donot have the track of the rooms and floors.

Comment: Try assigning a `row_number`, as a `suffix` or `prefix` to the name of the  Inputs in every row in frontend and then submit, that way you can have the track.

Comment: your `room_number` array indexes should have the values of the floor array. so you can differentiate the room_numbers according to the floor value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through each floor, count the number of rooms, and then determine which room numbers are associated with that floor by working through the array of room numbers.

*Given the array structure you're working with, the trick is that you'll need to have a loop like this one that can track the `$prev_index` by incrementing `$prev_index` by the room count at each floor.*

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'floor' => array(
        0 => '3',
        1 => '2',
        2 => '1',
    ),
    'room_count' => array(
        0 => '3',
        1 => '3',
        2 => '5',
    ),
    'room_number' => array(
        0  => '101',
        1  => '102',
        2  => '103',
        3  => '201',
        4  => '202',
        5  => '203',
        6  => '101',
        7  => '102',
        8  => '103',
        9  => '104',
        10 => '105',
    ),
);
for ($prev_index = 0, $i = 0; $i < count($array['floor']); ++$i) {
    $floor        = $array['floor'][$i];
    $room_count   = $array['room_count'][$i];
    $room_numbers = array_slice($array['room_number'], $prev_index, $room_count);
    $prev_index   = $prev_index + $room_count;

    echo 'Floor '.$floor.' has '.$room_count.' rooms, with room numbers '.implode(', ', $room_numbers)."\n";
}
```

---

```
Floor 3 has 3 rooms, with room numbers 101, 102, 103
Floor 2 has 3 rooms, with room numbers 201, 202, 203
Floor 1 has 5 rooms, with room numbers 101, 102, 103, 104, 105
```